# Reportviewer not loading .rdlc file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, report

I have a report viewer control in the asp.net page.
I created a .rdlc file with no dataset but just a textbox with text.
I attached the .rdlc file to the reportviewer but the report viewer is blank.

I'm wondering why a simple scenario as this was not working.

Comment: I am also wondering....:)
Just recheck by placing a table and put your textbox inside that table row. Remember don't put it in Table Header and Footer.

Comment: I think I have isolated the problem! I copy pasted the code and put it outside of any <asp:view> or <asp:multiview> tabs. The report worked fine.

I wish I could make it work inside the <asp:view> tab